# New Route in Laravel 9 Doesnt Appear

Tags: laravel-9

So... completely new to Laravel and I've run into a fairly basic problem.
I've googled this and searched through stackoverflow and cant find and answer.
I've added a new route into routes/web.php

```
Route::get('/contact', function () {
    return "It works.";
});
```

The whole web.php looks like this:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/contact', function () {
    return "It works.";
});
```

But I get a 404 when i try to access it.
Laravel is serving ok as I get the generic Laravel

I've tried:

```
php artisan route:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

But still doesn't show anything, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Laravel Version: Laravel v9.41.0 (PHP v8.1.8)

Thanks

Comment: Does it show up in `php artisan route:list`? How do you serve your project? How do you access that route?

Comment: @brombeer yes it does

Comment: UpdateConfigController
  GET|HEAD   api/user ....................................................................................... 
  GET|HEAD   contact ........................................................................................ 
  GET|HEAD   sanctum/csrf-cookie .......... sanctum.csrf-cookie › Laravel\Sanctum

Comment: @brombeer i serve it with php artisan:serve , its setup through apache2 and i can access it through the browser with no issues.

Comment: "_i serve it with php artisan:serve , its setup through apache2_" What does that mean? Apache is not involved when you use `php artisan:serve` - those are different unrelated tools. Do you have an Apache server running _and_ are using `php artisan:serve`? Different/wrong port maybe?

Comment: @brombeer ok thats probably my lack of understanding of Laravel, i "assumed" you still needed a web server to run it. I've disabled apache and that sorted it... waling away slightly embarrassed now! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Disabled Apache... all good... jeez its always the stupid things that get me.